# Template does not load angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to load a template using `Angular` controller. I have created everything needed:

- routes.config.js
- index.component.js
- index.config ( here is the config of the parent controller )
- html
- js controller
- connected with php controller

I already created templates and controllers exactly the same way and I have no idea what am I doing wrong. It's interesting that when I open elements tab in the browser I can see the `<statistic-test></statistic-test>` tags, and url also change. If I change `<statistic-test></statistic-test>` to another tag which is already used in another controller then it loads.

test-question.component.js

```
class TestQuestionController{
constructor($scope, $state,$stateParams, $compile, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, API){
    'ngInject';
    this.API = API
    this.$state = $state

    if ($stateParams.mode) {
      this.mode=$stateParams.mode
    }

     let Statics = API.service('show', API.all('statisticQuestion'))
     this.userlistaction = "app.statisticanswer.userlist"
}
$onInit(){}
}

export const TestQuestionComponent = {
templateUrl: './views/app/components/statistic-question-userlist/test-question.component.html',
controller: TestQuestionController,
controllerAs: 'vm',
bindings: {}
}
```

I also have an html named test-question.component.html

routes.config.statistic.question.js

```
export function RoutesConfigStatisticQuestion ($stateProvider) {
'ngInject'

$stateProvider
.state('app.statisticquestion', {
  url: '/statistic-question',
  data: {
    auth: true
  },
  views: {
    'main@app': {
      template: '<statistic-question></statistic-question>'
    }
  },
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
      label: 'Kérdések statisztika',
  }
})
.state('app.statisticquestion.test', {
  url: '/statistic-test/',
  data: {
    auth: true
  },
  views: {
    'main@app': {
      template: '<statistic-test></statistic-test>'
    }
  },
  params: {
    contentsId : null,
    alerts: null
  },
  ncyBreadcrumb: {
      label: 'Címke szerkesztése',
      parent: 'app.statisticquestion'
  }
})
```

If you have ANY idea how to solve this please share it with me.

Comment: hello, did you register the components in bootstrap app file?

Comment: Hello. No I did not. It's not autogenerated file?

Comment: I did register the components in index.component.js file. This is all I need

Comment: Any errors in the debug console or network tab?

Comment: This is the most annoying that there is no error, no warning, nothing.